# JavaScript using text field content as js function param

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this has an easy answer, but I don't know it.

so I have a widget that will let you get alerts texted to a phone. I am trying to store the info, but I can't get the user's input into my javascript function shown below:

```
    onClick="collect('info', 'nname=' + document.getObjectByID('Nname').value + ';num=12345;
```

How can I get the content as a string of a text field and use that in my function? Like I said, this is probably a relatively easy question for most, but I cannot figure it out :/

Comment: i think you can try somthing like this..if it is a text field.you can use document.getElementByID('Nname').value or if it is a DOM Element you can use document.getElementByID('Nname').innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your method signature is something like following:

```
function collect(a,b,c)
```

the onclick should be like

```
onclick="collect('info', document.getElementByID('Nname').value, 12345)"
```

You do not have to pass the parameters as you passing GET variables in http requests

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you were missing the last `'` to close and no `)` + you are missing the `getElementById`

```
onClick="collect('info', 'nname=' + document.getElementById('Nname').value + ';num=12345');"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getElementById` instead of `getObjectById`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onClick="collect('info', 'nname=' + document.getElementById('Nname').value + ';num=12345;');"
```

Answer (score 0):

For better clarity, u should follow this

```
function collect(a, b, c) {
   var A = a;
   var B = b + document.getElementByID('Nname').value 
   // do your work
}
```

the onclick should be like

```
onclick="collect('info','nname=', ';num=12345')"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="collect('info', 'Nname')"

function collect(a, b){
   var param = 'nname=' + document.getElementById(b).value + ';num=12345;
   ...
}
```